# Payara: Como ingresar a mi aplicacion sin especificar el puerto

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

no he encontrado como hacer para ingresar a una aplicacion java corriendo sobre Payara sin especificar el puerto, por ejemplo: https://localhost:8080/miapp, como puedo
cambiar a https://localhost/miapp

se puede lograr?, se que con apache es posible, pero no encontre informacion con Payara.
Saludos y muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier informacion.

Comment: "Sin especificar puerto" significa que el servidor escuche en los puertos estándar: el 80 para http y el 443 para https

Comment: ya intentaste cambiarle el puerto a 80 para http?